# Spring Hibernate validator not working but javax is

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc

Having some trouble with Spring Validation and the Hibernate Validator.

I am using Spring 4 and Hibernate Validator 5, my problem is that the javax annotations are acting properly but it looks like the Hibernate annotations are not getting invoked.

Here is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void create(@RequestBody @Valid CreatePlantCommand command, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletResponse response){

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        // do something
    }

    // do work

    // should set the location header on new requests
    String location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
            .pathSegment("{code}").buildAndExpand(code)
            .toUriString();

    response.setHeader("Location", location);
}
```

and the command object

```
public class CreatePlantCommand {

    @NotNull
    private Integer code;

    @Length(min = 1, max = 5)
    //@Max(5)
    private String description;

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

The NotNull and Max (its commented out right now) are working, but Length seems to be completely ignored. If I use Size, it works, if I use any Hibernate annotation its ignored.

I am using the LocalValidatorFactoryBean from Spring

```
<bean id='validator' class='org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean'/>
```

Why would the Hibernate Validations not be applied?

**EDIT**

Continuing to try and understand what is happening here.

I have noticed the NotEmpty validation is the only one that works. I can put it on the description field and not send it, and I will get the error. If I put, Email, CreditCard or Url on the description and send it incorrect data, I don't get the error.

**EDIT**

I've created a small project that is demonstrating some of this behavior. Its on my bitbucket repo at https://bitbucket.org/joeyoung/hibernate-validation-problems.

The Form object has 4 public properties, two are commented out, that use the @Length and @Email validators.

```
public class Form {

    @Length(max=10)
    public String name;

    @Email
    public String email;

//  @Range(min=18)
//  public Integer age;

//    @CreditCardNumber
//    public String creditCard;
}
```

If I post this json;

```
{
  "name":"adafasdfasfdsafd",
  "email":"adf",
  "age":1,
  "creditCard":"123456"
}
```

To this controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/form")
public class FormController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    public List<FieldError> submitForm(@RequestBody @Valid Form form, BindingResult result) {

        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return result.getFieldErrors();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

No errors are returned.

If I uncomment the @Range field and Post again, I get @Email and @Range errors, not @Length.

I'm assuming I am doing something wrong and any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Server wise, I am using WebSphere Liberty 8.5 and my server.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="Default Liberty Server">
  <!-- Enable features -->
  <featureManager>
    <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
    <feature>jpa-2.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>beanValidation-1.0</feature>
  </featureManager>
  <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
  <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" />
  <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean" />
  <application id="problems_war_exploded" location="C:\Users\jyoung\Code\hibernate-validation-problems\target\problems-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" name="problems_war_exploded" type="war" context-root="/hibernate-validation-problems" />
</server>
```

Comment: It's very strange.. Could you provide a working example which allow to reproduce it?

Comment: @SlavaSemushin, I've made some edits and linked to a project that is giving me the same problems. Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Ugh. Turns out this is a Websphere issue. Running inside Tomcat everything works ok. A quick googling around for Websphere and the Hibernate validator shows that Websphere is loading its own on top of the Hibernate one.

Which explains why the Hibernate annotations are not working.